# Why does python puts a space in front of my formatted string

Tags: python, string, formatted-text

I have started to learn python recently and found it very fascinating. However when I try formatted strings, `f"{var}..."` I got a redundant space in front of it.

This is my code:

```py
# Formatted Strings
segment1 = "First segment"
segment2 = "Second segment"
notFormatted = "First: " + segment1 + " Second: " + segment2 + "\n"  # This is hard to read / maintain
formatted = f"First: {segment1} Second: {segment2} \n"  # This approach is much cleaner
print(notFormatted, formatted)  # Should output same text
```

What I got: [In console]

```
First: First segment Second: Second segment
 First: First segment Second: Second segment
```

As shown above the the second line starts with a space and ends with a space
I know I can use the strip function to remove it but I am curious why is it there. Is it because the `\n` ?

---

**Update:**

```py
# Formatted Strings
segment1 = "First segment"
segment2 = "Second segment"
notFormatted = "First: " + segment1 + " Second: " + segment2 + "\n".strip()  # This is hard to read / maintain
formatted = f"First: {segment1} Second: {segment2} \n".strip()  # This approach is much cleaner
print(notFormatted, formatted)  # Should output same text
```

This code's out put merges two lines together so how should I solve this?

Comment: Try `print(notFormatted + formatted)` (a simpler example: `print(1, 2)`).

Comment: Or `print(notFormatted, formatted, sep="")`

Comment: Yes, the cause is that you're submitting a pair of strings - try `print ( "a", "b")` - the print statement prints them differently to how it would print a single string `print("a" + "b")`.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in python [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), `print` function as--

`print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`

So print function takes a default separator of `' '`, that is why you are getting extra space. You can remove it by

```py
print(notFormatted, formatted, sep='')  # Should output same text
```

output

```
First: First segment Second: Second segment
First: First segment Second: Second segment
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because the  `,` in the `print(notFormatted,formatted)` puts a space between the two printed things. and since your `notFormatted` has a `\n` at the end, and then python puts the space, your printed lines have a space after the new line.

Try this instead: `print(notFormatted + formatted)`

Comment: I do not think it is the whitespace after/before the ```,``` because I tried these before asking this question :)

Comment: It's not the whitespace beefore/after the `,`, but print by default has a space as the separator, so that's why you get the space...

Comment: the spaces in the python code doesnt make any difference. instead the print function puts a space where the `,` is. try `print("1","2")` and `print("1"+"2")`

Comment: @LaraIpek this is not a correct way to put it. "," simply separates the function arguments. and when you are performing `print("1"+"2")` then at first the argument is evaluated which becomes "12" as a result of string concatenation. Then the `print` is called like `print("12")`